# Django syncdb with ManytoMany field through class

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create the database tables for a Django Project. There is a ManyToMany Relationship between *Arzt* and *Fachbereich* through *ArztFachbereich*.

```
class Fachbereich(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='FachID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=100)

class Arzt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fachbereich = models.ManyToManyField(Fachbereich, through=ArztFachbereich)

class ArztFachbereich(FachbereichUndArztFachbereiche):
    arzt = models.ForeignKey(Arzt)
    fachbereich = models.ForeignKey(Fachbereich)
```

After executing syncdb I get *NameError: name 'ArztFachbereich' is not defined*

When I change places of Arzt and ArztFachbeeich I get the same NameError just with Arzt. 
Is there a way to do this? Or should I do this manualy in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the model passed to the `through` argument.

Change it to:

```
fachbereich = models.ManyToManyField(Fachbereich, through='ArztFachbereich')
```

Example in docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

EDIT:

As noted by Andrew in comments, putting the model in quotes makes the evaluation lazy, so the ORM will parse all classes first before coming back to it.

Comment: Yes, this makes the evaluation of `ArztFachbereich` lazy, so that the ORM will parse all classes first and then come back and find the referenced field.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks, that works. I actually build this with that example, but it seems I was not able to see those quotes^^